# FabricJs group selection JSON stringify

Tags: jquery, fabricjs

I want to make a history of my options in FabricJs. I used an example from here and it works well exept if I select 2 object and move them.

When I select 2 object or more they move a half the width of the bounding box bottom and right and when I deselect them they move a on left and top.

Here is the JsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/be1xc5xs/

```
function updateModifications(savehistory) {
    if (savehistory === true) {
        myjson = JSON.stringify(canvas); // this is the problem
        state.push(myjson);
    }
}
```

Comment: Choose the latest version of fabric.js from the jsfiddle dropdown. Works fine with 1.5.0

Comment: yes ... it works :) I had 1.4.0. Thank you